# Dart Editor PUB Package Manager cannot find path.dart

Tags: dart, editor, dart-pub

After Installing Dart and Dart Editor I consistently get the following error on different DartLang.org code samples:

```
--- 5:00:06 PM Auto running pub get on C:\dart\sample-tracker-master ... ---  
Pub get failed, [1] Resolving dependencies...  
Could not find package path.dart at https://pub.dartlang.org.  
Depended on by:  
- tracker 0.0.0
```

Why is PUB Manager unable to to find this package?

Pubspec.yaml contents follow:

```
name: polymer_and_dart
description: Sample app built with the polymer.dart package
environment:
  sdk: '>=1.2.0 <2.0.0'
dependencies:
  polymer: '>=0.15.1 <0.16.0'
dev_dependencies:
  unittest: '>=0.10.0 <0.11.0'
transformers:
- polymer:
    entry_points:
    - web/begin/index.html
    - web/end/index.html
```

Comment: Can you please add the content of your `pubspec.yaml` file to your question.

Comment: Here are the pubspec.yaml file contents: name: polymer_and_dart
description: Sample app built with the polymer.dart package
environment:
  sdk: '>=1.2.0 <2.0.0'
dependencies:
  polymer: '>=0.15.1 <0.16.0'
dev_dependencies:
  unittest: '>=0.10.0 <0.11.0'
transformers:
- polymer:
    entry_points:
    - web/begin/index.html
    - web/end/index.html

Comment: Pubspec.yaml seems fine. Can you please try `pub cache repair` on the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `pubspec.yaml` looks fine. IMO, The problem is breakage of cache directory.

Many people seems to meet this issue, See [Link](https://plus.google.com/113415344870093527255/posts/Tab8xQnqoFs)

If `pub cache repair` cannot fix this issue.

You can manually delete package cache directory. and run `pub get` again.

From Windows. Delete `C:\Users\<your account>\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache` manually. and run `pub get`.

Hope this work.

Comment: I received errors running the pub cache repair command.  However, deleting the Cache folder and running pub get command seems to have resolved the issue.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: @JoeFontana Yeah.. Sadly this happen. I believe Dart team start working on this!

Answer (score 1):

Can you please add the content of your `pubspec.yaml` file to your question. `path.dart` is not a valid package name, the name of the package is only `path`. When you want to use a library of the `path` package you import `package:path/path.dart` though but in `pubspec.yaml` you reference the package name which doesn't have a `.dart` extension.